# how to change my grid view in horizontal view?

Tags: android, imageview

Hi now i am create thumbnails images.....but I wish to create images in horizontal view..
how to change my grid view in horizontal.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use , HorizontalScrollView as parent layout and inside it use , ImagViews.

Or you can use GalleryView.